# Как проверить состояние переменной перед переключением

Tags: java, android

Весь код, относящийся к вопросу:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static class Timer {
        static boolean active = true;
        static int level = 100;
        static int start = 3650;
        static int stop = 7200;
    }

static class Pump{
    static boolean active = true;
    static int start = 3600;
    static int working = 3000;
    }

static class CO2{
    static boolean active = true;
    static Timer[] timerCO2 = new Timer[4];
    }
static class Channel{
        static boolean active = true;
        static int startDay = 3600;
        static int stopDay = 82800;
        static Timer[] timer = new Timer[4];
    }
    Channel[] channel = new Channel[9];

public int chNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Switch switchCh = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchCh);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCh = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ch);
    adapterCh.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner spinnerCh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCh);
    spinnerCh.setAdapter(adapterCh);
    spinnerCh.setSelection(0);
    spinnerCh.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            chNum = position;
            switchCh.setChecked(channel[chNum].active);
            System.out.println ("spinnerCh " + chNum + " " + channel[chNum].active);

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

    switchCh.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            channel[chNum].active = isChecked;
            System.out.println ("switchCh " + chNum + " " + channel[chNum].active);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Сначала объявляется класс, который редактируется в приложении с помощью спиннеров, свитчеров и намберпикеров. Показаны только первый спиннер, переключающий переменную chNum, являющуюся индексом для доступа к элементам класса channel. Спиннер после выбора chNum с помощью функции `switchCh.setChecked(channel[chNum].active);` выбирает редактируемый канал и выставляет свитчер в положение, соответствующее актуальному значению переменной `channel[chNum].active)`. Но свитчер в этой строчке:`channel[chNum].active = isChecked;` успевает ее переписать в тру или фельс, в зависимости от того, в каком положении он был раньше. Вопрос: как ЗАРАНЕЕ выставить свитчер в положение, равное `channel[chNum].active` а ПОТОМ уже изменять этим же свитчером `channel[chNum].active` по желанию пользователя. В XML только разметка активити, ничего относящегося к рабочему коду там нет.
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы в момент выставления статуса не срабатывал листенер, надо его отключать (отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523518/5892568)

```
switchCh.setOnCheckedChangeListener (null);
switchCh.setChecked (..);
switchCh.setOnCheckedChangeListener ( листенер сохраненый в переменную в OnCreate);
```

Comment: Очевидно, я должен уведомить адаптер свитчера а не адаптер спиннера? Можно поподробней?

Comment: Напомню, мне нужно управлять состоянием свитчера с помощью спиннера через переменную, а потом уже менять свитчером эту же переменную.

Comment: Приведите тогда Layout и примерный вид нового списка. Вообще выглядит как очень нестандартное поведение.

Comment: Но вообще после того как адаптеру скажете спиннер должен перерисовать данные.

Comment: Кода много, словами: Проблема не в спиннере, а в свитчере! Свитчер должен словить состояние  channel[chNum].active, и показать мне его, то есть если channel[chNum].active был изначально false, свитчер должен принять положение "off", если channel[chNum].active является true, свитчер должен стать "on". После этого пользователь свитчером меняет channel[chNum].active на тру или фельс. Спиннер меняет только индекс переменной из массива, подаваемого в адаптер свитчера. Надеюсь, объяснил.

Comment: Без картинки и кода лейаута тяжеловато понять что надо, но сразу могу сказать что не выглядить как стандартное поведение.

Comment: Добавил код с объяснениями